Issues after reinstalling SharePoint Server Subscription Edition
I had SharePoint Server 2019 installed in Windows Server 2019 Standard edition. I uninstalled it and installed SharePoint Server Subscription Edition. Installation seemed to be OK, but when I migrated the database from old environment, I started getting some issues like:
The DataSourceId of 'TopNavigationMenu' must be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource. A control with ID 'topSiteMap' could not be found, I had to reinstall SharePoint Server subscription Edition.
After reinstalling it, SharePoint Server Subscription Edition on Win Server 2019, I started getting this error when Product Configuration Wizzard tried to open Central Admin after it completed:
Service Unavailable: http error 503.

Central Admin's Application pool was stopping. So I looked in Event viewer and found out the following:
IIS-W3SVC-WP:
The module DLL 'c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\isapi\sprequestfilteringmodule.dll' failed to load. The data is the error.

I checked the location in 16 hive and there was no sprequestfilteringmodule.dll. I copied it from another machine and Central Admin starting working fine.
Then I ran CU of April 2024, and after it completed, everything stopped working.
It will return:
This page isn't working. [Server name] is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP Error 500.


I have the same issue. After updating to April 2024 in CU in our pre production.
Steps in this article fix the issue however cannot find any KB relevant to server version and April 2024 CU yet.
https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2023/04/14/trending-issue-503-response-on-sp2016-servers-running-on-windows-server-2012-r2-after-installing-april-2023-cu/
I have a missing language independent CU so am testing if this affects also.

I saw the post and found the exact same workaround in another post. It has a link to the post you mentioned above:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1228993/recent-sp-security-update-causes-iis-to-throw-a-50
I will accept your answer.
